# TFS 2008 Warehouse Job

Tags: tfs

In TFS2008, is there anyone to tell the Warehouse Controller job to do a full rebuild of the Analysis Services Cube everytime? I know this can be done in TFS 2010 but I can't seem to find any information regarding this for TFS 2008.

If not then would it be a bad idea for me to schedule in a task to manual rebuild the cube just before the warehouse job runs every 5 hours or so ?

Comment: Should be stable enough to allow regular complete rebuilds every time. But just out of curiosity, why do you need a complete rebuild everytime?

Comment: Our analysis server didn't have enough space to support an incremental build because it backs up the cube every time and builds it again. Didn't know how to stop it from doing that so had to run a full build every time to make it work. Finally got the extra space put in so this isn't an issue anymore! Thanks for the reply :)